# When creating a label a label inside a panel, the text is cut off VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to be able to dynamically create a panel with a label on it, but the label isn't acting as I would expect it too, its cutting most of it off.

When I create a panel then create a label inside the panel, the text isn't displayed correctly. Anyone know how to fix it?

What is was supposed to do was to create a panel with text on it with the newpanel() sub

```
Dim timetable(5, 5) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Width = (74 * 5) - 3
    Me.Height = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size.Height
    Me.Top = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Top
    Me.Left = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Right - Me.Width
    GetTimetable()
End Sub





Private Sub newpanel(colour As Color, textT As String)
    Dim Npan As New Panel
    Npan.Top = 0
    Npan.Left = 0
    Npan.Width = Me.Width
    Npan.Height = 64
    Npan.BackColor = colour
    Dim NpanT As New Label
    NpanT.Parent = Npan

    NpanT.Text = textT

    Npan.Controls.Add(NpanT)

    Me.Controls.Add(Npan)


End Sub

Private Sub GetTimetable()
    'Dim path As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\Timetable"
    newpanel(Color.Aqua, "this is a test! test testtesttest test test test")
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "acting weird" exactly mean? Bear in mind that you are not setting almost any property for the Label and thus it takes the default values (including location inside the Panel).

Comment: Acting weird means that it acts differently than your expectations. You need to specify what did you expect and what did you get instead. Also, the text isn't displayed correctly means that you have a problem with the way your text is displayed. Again, you need to describe what did you expect and what did you get instead. You cannot expect us to tell you how can you achieve what you want if you do not specify what you want,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the MSDN page for the [`Label.AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx) Property, it states as was mentioned above that the Labels AutoSize Property defaults to true in the designer, **but** it is **false** when created in code.

From above link:

> When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true. When instantiated from code, the default value is false.

So you need to change your `newpanel` method to this:

```
Private Sub newpanel(colour As Color, textT As String)
    Dim Npan As New Panel
    Npan.Top = 0
    Npan.Left = 0
    Npan.Width = Me.Width
    Npan.Height = 64
    Npan.BackColor = colour
    Dim NpanT As New Label
    NpanT.Parent = Npan

    NpanT.Text = textT
    NpanT.AutoSize = True  'Enables Auto sizing
    Npan.Controls.Add(NpanT)
    Me.Controls.Add(Npan)
End Sub
```